# KPI montioring for e-commerce

Tags: open-source, monitoring, ecommerce

I'm looking for a monitoring tool, that is able monitor multiple e-commerce sites at once and is able to alert if one of the sites is behaving abnormal.

Some examples:

- It should monitor sales on all sites and should generate graphs of sales count and revenue. It should alert if the sales count of one machine decreases in an abnormal way (for example if it's below a treshold or if it is significatly lower than the count of a comparative period of the previous week)
- It should monitor failed payments on all sites and should alert if there is a significant increase in failed payments
- It should monitor and alert downtimes

The easiest would be if it is getting this data from multiple databases where all the information is stored. But we would consider other ways too.

We would prefer an open source solution, but also a commercial solution would be fine if it fit's our needs.

A self-hosted solution would be preferable, but we would also consider a cloud solution. We would host it on AWS in a Linux container, depending on the requirements of the tool. The e-commerce sites are custom build solutions - we would take care of the integration. I think we would consider spending up to US$49-69 per month.

Comment: Thanks! Integrated that with your question (not you can always [edit] your posts to refine them, as you certainly know). Besides, funny how commerce kicked in even in customers' price estimations: So $50-70 would be too much, as commerce always makes the price slightly below? ;) Uh, speaking about: Canadian, Australian, or US$? :D

Comment: +/- $5 is fine - just used to that kind of pricing ;)
I'm talking about USD.